# Tables in appendix not displayed after certain point

Tags: tables

I have an appendix with around 25 tables, and after the inclusion of 18 tables the following are not displayed anymore:

```
    % Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Turnlokale 1930'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
 \caption{Distribution of gym spaces for cantons 1930}
  \tiny
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
    \hline
    Organization & Sports hall & Basement or shed & Hall  & Barn  & Insufficient spaces & No gym space \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    AG    & 80    & 35    & 24    & 6     & 9     & 6 \bigstrut[t]\\
    AP    & 13    & 6     & 5     & 1     & 2     & 0 \\
    BL    & 22    & 7     & 5     & 8     & 3     & 1 \\
    BS    & 18    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    BE    & 95    & 8     & 48    & 4     & 6     & 2 \\
    C     & 13    & 3     & 2     & 1     & 4     & 1 \\
    FR    & 7     & 1     & 4     & 1     & 0     & 0 \\
    GE    & 11    & 0     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    GL    & 16    & 4     & 4     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    GR    & 20    & 2     & 4     & 1     & 0     & 2 \\
    LU    & 20    & 4     & 8     & 0     & 9     & 2 \\
    NE    & 30    & 1     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 0 \\
    SH    & 14    & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 0 \\
    SO    & 46    & 10    & 16    & 4     & 2     & 0 \\
    SG    & 52    & 16    & 4     & 3     & 3     & 2 \\
    TI    & 11    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    TG    & 24    & 13    & 4     & 9     & 8     & 1 \\
    VS    & 10    & 2     & 2     & 0     & 1     & 0 \\
    VD    & 56    & 4     & 7     & 3     & 4     & 0 \\
    ZH    & 99    & 36    & 10    & 19    & 9     & 0 \bigstrut[b]\\
    \hline
    Total & 657   & 154   & 150   & 62    & 62    & 17 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\begin{sidewaysfigure}[h!]
\caption{Membership development of 17 oldest associations that were part of the Zurich gymnastics organization 1871-1911 }
\includegraphics[width=20cm,keepaspectratio]{appendixcommunitymembers}
\centering
    \captionsetup{font={scriptsize}}
    \caption*{Soure: Eidgenössischer Turnverein (1870-1930) and Spühler (1911), own illustration}
\centering
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}[h!]
\caption{Active members development of 17 oldest associations that were part of the Zurich gymnastics organization 1871-1911 }
\includegraphics[width=20cm,keepaspectratio]{appendixcommunityactive}
\centering
    \captionsetup{font={scriptsize}}
    \caption*{Soure: Eidgenössischer Turnverein (1870-1930) and Spühler (1911), own illustration}
\centering
\end{sidewaysfigure}

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Detailbestand 1911'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Account of the Zurich gymnastics organization 1911}
  \tiny
    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LLLLLLL}
    \hlinewd{1.25pt}
          & Year of foundation & Year of admittance to cantonal organization & Paying members & Non-Paying members & Total members & Active members \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    Zürich, Alte Sektion & 1820  & 1862  & 610   & 83    & 693   & 88 \bigstrut[t]\\
    Neumünster & 1862  & 1863  & 466   & 148   & 614   & 65 \\
    Aussersihl & 1868  & 1870  & 477   & 124   & 601   & 94 \\
    Stadtturnverein Winterthur & 1845  & 1860  & 307   & 163   & 470   & 53 \\
    Thalwil & 1864  & 1866  & 367   & 95    & 462   & 50 \\
    Hottingen & 1877  & 1878  & 328   & 50    & 378   & 45 \\
    Töss  & 1870  & 1871  & 284   & 81    & 365   & 66 \\
    Wiedikon & 1874  & 1875  & 289   & 58    & 347   & 76 \\
    Seebach & 1873  & 1875  & 242   & 68    & 310   & 42 \\
    Veltheim & 1877  & 1878  & 263   & 42    & 305   & 28 \\
    Männerturnverein Zürich & 1858  & 1875  & 208   & 84    & 292   & - \\
    Rüti  & 1872  & 1872  & 252   & 38    & 290   & 38 \\
    Oerlikon & 1877  & 1878  & 227   & 54    & 281   & 41 \\
    Altstetten & 1874  & 1875  & 186   & 94    & 280   & 28 \\
    Horgen & 1862  & 1863  & 165   & 75    & 240   & 34 \\
    Zürich-Industriequartier & 1898  & 1898  & 203   & 22    & 225   & 45 \\
    Winterthur-Tössfeld-Schönthal & 1895  & 1898  & 213   & 7     & 220   & 35 \\
    Enge  & 1870  & 1871  & 164   & 55    & 219   & 23 \\
    Wipkingen & 1879  & 1881  & 150   & 65    & 215   & 35 \\
    Männerturnverein Winterthur & 1861  & 1879  & 155   & 55    & 210   & - \\
    Höngg & 1869  & 1890  & 182   & 26    & 208   & 43 \\
    Oberstrass & 1876  & 1877  & 153   & 53    & 206   & 38 \\
    Unterstrass & 1864  & 1864  & 154   & 47    & 201   & 36 \\
    Wädenswil & 1848  & 1860  & 180   & 16    & 196   & 34 \\
    Männerturnverein Aussersihl & 1878  & 1883  & 150   & 40    & 190   & - \\
    Fluntern  & 1876  & 1878  & 165   & 22    & 187   & 18 \\
    Deutsche Turnerschaft Zürich & 1861  & 1877  & 145   & 38    & 183   & 47 \\
    Wald  & 1865  & 1870  & 167   & 12    & 179   & 31 \\
    Uster & 1861  & 1863  & 156   & 14    & 170   & 32 \\
    Turnsektion des K. V. Zürich & 1877  & 1885  & 153   & 16    & 169   & 51 \\
    Grütliturnverein Winterthur & 1875  & 1878  & 130   & 34    & 164   & 32 \\
    Schlieren & 1886  & 1893  & 136   & 23    & 159   & 22 \\
    Wüfllingen & 1875  & 1877  & 125   & 32    & 157   & 31 \\
    Bassersdorf & 1883  & 1884  & 124   & 28    & 152   & 20 \\
    Zollikon & 1885  & 1890  & 128   & 24    & 152   & 20 \\
    Dietikon & 1878  & 1904  & 125   & 24    & 149   & 25 \\
    Oberwinterthur & 1881  & 1884  & 128   & 20    & 148   & 32 \\
    Bürgerturnverein Küsnacht & 1861  & 1875  & 130   & 15    & 145   & 30 \\
    Wollishofen & 1885  & 1889  & 124   & 19    & 143   & 24 \\
    Stäfa & 1872  & 1875  & 103   & 37    & 140   & 32 \\
    Dürnten & 1894  & 1898  & 132   & 3     & 135   & 23 \\
    Männerturnverein Wiedikon & 1889  & 1896  & 65    & 65    & 130   & - \\
    Bürgerturnverein Zürich & 1878  & 1881  & 102   & 22    & 124   & 38 \\
    Bauma & 1906  & 1909  & 120   & 2     & 122   & 18 \\
    Dübendorf & 1882  & 1893  & 111   & 10    & 121   & 16 \\
    Kilchberg & 1877  & 1880  & 110   & 10    & 120   & 15 \\
    Winterthur-Pflanzschule-Geiselweid & ?     & 1904  & 110   & 10    & 120   & 18 \\
    Langnau a. A. & 1880  & 1881  & 90    & 28    & 118   & 18 \\
    Rüschlikon & 1882  & 1885  & 94    & 24    & 118   & 16 \\
    Richterswil & 1876  & 1878  & 98    & 17    & 115   & 24 \\
    Grafstall & 1889  & 1895  & 95    & 20    & 115   & 21 \\
    Wetzikon & 1861  & 1863  & 92    & 21    & 113   & 28 \\
    Grütliturnverein Aussersihl & 1882  & 1883  & 88    & 25    & 113   & 38 \\
    Männedorf & 1868  & 1886  & 96    & 14    & 110   & 16 \\
    Jüdischer Turnverein Zürich & 1908  & 1911  & 105   & 3     & 108   & 24 \\
    Seen  & 1883  & 1885  & 92    & 15    & 107   & 17 \\
    Grütliturnverein Wädenswil & 1898  & 1902  & 96    & 8     & 104   & 26 \\
    Neftenbach & 1877  & 1880  & 79    & 23    & 102   & 23 \\
    Seminarturnverein Küsnacht & 1870  & 1873  & 48    & 50    & 98    & 48 \\
    Hombrechtikon & 1897  & 1899  & 80    & 17    & 97    & 12 \\
    Albisrieden & 1891  & 1896  & 80    & 16    & 96    & 20 \\
    Adliswil & 1881  & 1882  & 80    & 15    & 95    & 26 \\
    Hinwil & 1881  & 1882  & 82    & 7     & 89    & 18 \\
    Affoltern b. Z. & 1883  & 1886  & 76    & 12    & 88    & 15 \\
    Flurlingen & 1901  & 1908  & 78    & 9     & 87    & 18 \\
    Uetikon a. See & 1886  & 1901  & 67    & 19    & 86    & 16 \\
    Pfungen & 1884  & 1905  & 78    & 8     & 86    & 16 \\
    Pfäffikon & 1872  & 1898  & 80    & 5     & 85    & 15 \\
    Wallisellen & 1887  & 1890  & 74    & 9     & 83    & 21 \\
    Kloten & 1896  & 1901  & 75    & 8     & 83    & 11 \\
    Ottenbach & 1882  & 1889  & 66    & 15    & 81    & 19 \\
    Bülach & 1895  & 1901  & 73    & 8     & 81    & 16 \\
    Erlenbach & 1899  & 1904  & 75    & 6     & 81    & 13 \\
    Meilen & 1879  & 1879  & 50    & 30    & 80    & 14 \\
    Schwamendingen & 1884  & 1884  & 62    & 18    & 80    & 17 \\
    Deutscher Turnverein Winterthur & 1888  & 1898  & 71    & 9     & 80    & 15 \\
    Engstringen & 1903  & 1906  & 76    & 4     & 80    & 14 \\
    Riesbach & 1908  & 1908  & 76    & 4     & 80    & 25 \\
    Obfelden & 1881  & 1886  & 65    & 13    & 78    & 16 \\
    Glattfelden & 1889  & 1898  & 62    & 15    & 77    & 12 \\
    Wiesendangen & 1893  & 1898  & 73    & 4     & 77    & 11 \\
    Elgg  & 1893  & 1901  & 70    & 6     & 76    & 12 \\
    Mettmenstetten & 1874  & 1901  & 60    & 12    & 72    & 14 \\
    Grütliturnverein Wipkingen & 1895  & 1898  & 57    & 9     & 66    & 18 \\
    Brüttisellen & 1898  & 1899  & 58    & 7     & 65    & 15 \\
    Kaufm. Turnsektion Winterthur & 1899  & 1908  & 65    & -     & 65    & 20 \\
    Turbenthal & 1899  & 1904  & 60    & 2     & 62    & 18 \\
    Freienstein & 1879  & 1882  & 54    & 4     & 58    & 16 \\
    Rorbas & 1881  & 1884  & 54    & 4     & 58    & 19 \\
    Dielsdorf & 1878  & 1886  & 50    & 6     & 56    & 18 \\
    Abstinententurnverein Zürich & 1910  & 1910  & 55    & -     & 55    & 20 \\
    Embrach & 1885  & 1895  & 42    & 9     & 51    & 14 \\
    Hedingen & 1899  & 1904  & 41    & 10    & 51    & 13 \\
    Affoltern a. A. & 1877  & 1880  & 40    & 10    & 50    & 18 \\
    Grüningen & 1907  & 1908  & 50    & -     & 50    & 16 \\
    Rümlang & 1907  & 1908  & 47    & 1     & 48    & 16 \\
    Rykon & 1892  & 1898  & 38    & 7     & 45    & 12 \\
    Gossau & 1895  & 1906  & 40    & 5     & 45    & 12 \\
    Aathal-Seegräben & 1897  & 1907  & 44    & 1     & 45    & 9 \\
    Birmensdorf & 1887  & 1895  & 38    & 6     & 44    & 12 \\
    Bäretswil & 1881  & 1901  & 40    & 4     & 44    & 14 \\
    Andelfingen & 1882  & 1901  & 32    & 11    & 43    & 18 \\
    Herrliberg & 1901  & 1902  & 35    & 8     & 43    & 8 \\
    Egg   & 1902  & 1907  & 40    & 3     & 43    & 10 \\
    Männerturnverein Thalwil & 1873  & 1885  & 30    & 12    & 42    & - \\
    Technikum Winterthur & 1896  & 1898  & 32    & 10    & 42    & 17 \\
    Niederglatt & 1902  & 1905  & 38    & 3     & 41    & 12 \\
    Fehraltorf & 1898  & 1904  & 30    & 6     & 36    & 10 \\
    Bubikon & 1892  & 1902  & 25    & 8     & 33    & 18 \\
    Männerturnverein Hottingen & 1891  & 1893  & 30    & 1     & 31    & - \\
    Räterschen & 1892  & 1902  & 26    & 5     & 31    & 12 \\
    Universitätsturnverein Zürich & 1873  & 1875  & 30    & -     & 30    & 16 \\
    Rafz  & 1907  & 1908  & 30    & -     & 30    & 16 \\
    Illnau & 1899  & 1907  & 20    & 7     & 27    & 8 \\
    Männerturnverein Unterstrass & 1884  & 1908  & 25    & -     & 25    & - \\
    Männerturnverein Rüti & 1890  & 1909  & 16    & 8     & 24    & - \\
    Kantonsschülerturnverein Zürich & 1886  & 1909  & 20    & -     & 20    & 20 \\
    Männerturnverein Wädenswil & 1869  & 1886  & 18    & -     & 18    & - \\
    Urdorf & 1899  & 1904  & 13    & 5     & 18    & 11 \\
    Männerturnverein Küsnacht & 1899  & 1906  & 16    & -     & 16    & - \\
    Dietlikon & 1896  & 1898  & 14    & -     & 14    & 14 \bigstrut[b]\\
    \hline
    Total &       &       & 13'359 & 2'812 & 16'171 & 2'767 \bigstrut\\
    \hlinewd{1.25pt}
    \end{tabulary}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Mitgliederbewegung 1895-1953'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
  \scriptsize
    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LRRRRRRRRR}
    Season & Clubs &       & Active & Seniors & Juniors & Total & Honorary- and free & Passive & Total \\
    1895  & 11    &       & 120   &       &       &       &       &       & 120 \\
    1896  & 12    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    1897/98 & 8     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    1898/99 & 9     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    1899/1900 & 12    &       & 547   &       & 15    &       &       & 446   & \textbf{1'008} \\
    1900/01 & 19    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & 1'621 \\
    1901/02 & 26    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    1902/03 & 38    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    1903/04 & 42    &       & 1'750 &       &       &       &       & 1'864 & 3'614 \\
    1904/05 & 44    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    1905/06 & 49    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    1906/07 & 50    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    1907/08 & 54    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    1908/09 & 59    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    1909/10 & 60    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    1910/11 & 63    &       & 2'966 &       &       &       & 270   & 3'921 & 7'157 \\
    1911/12 & 61    &       & 3'282 & 288   & 341   & 3'911 & 836   & 5'045 & 9'792 \\
    1912/13 & 88    &       & 3'647 & 475   & 536   & 4'658 & 1'060 & 5'545 & 11'263 \\
    1913/14 & 115   &       & 5'588 & 409   & 746   & 6'743 & 1'049 & 7'464 & 15'256 \\
    1914/15 & -     &       & -     & -     & -     & 0     & -     & -     & 15'180 \\
    1915/16 & 102   &       & 8'573 & 241   & 573   & 9'387 & 1'317 & 6'911 & 17'615 \\
    1916/17 & 109   &       & 4'274 & 490   & 658   & 5'422 & 1'656 & 6'486 & 13'564 \\
    1917/18 & 116   &       & 5'080 & 367   & 687   & 6'134 & 1'559 & 6'951 & 14'644 \\
    1918/19 & 126   &       & 5'555 & 476   & 704   & 6'735 & 4'958 & 9'000 & 20'693 \\
    1919/20 & 161   &       & 7'959 & 678   & 1'066 & 9'703 & 6'672 & 12'367 & 28'742 \\
    1920/21 & 185   &       & 10'549 & 1'196 & 2'673 & 14'418 & 8'305 & 16'957 & 39'680 \\
    1921/22 & 207   &       & 9'557 & 1'286 & 3'405 & 14'248 & 12'636 & 19'681 & 46'565 \\
    1922/23 & 229   &       & 16'682 & 1'482 & 3'554 & 21'718 & 3'349 & 27'028 & 52'095 \\
    1923/24 & 230   &       & 15'367 & 1'558 & 3'403 & 20'328 & 3'420 & 27'967 & 51'715 \\
    1924/25 & 236   &       & 15'577 & 1'342 & 3'261 & 20'180 & 3'721 & 27'866 & 51'767 \\
    1925/26 & 261   &       & 15'030 & 1'298 & 2'872 & 19'200 & 3'737 & 28'253 & 51'190 \\
    1926/27 & 268   &       & 14'573 & 1'321 & 2'357 & 18'251 & 3'982 & 27'781 & 50'014 \\
    1927/28 & 292   &       & 15'366 & 1'893 & 2'496 & 19'755 & 3'651 & 30'557 & 53'963 \\
    1928/29 & 311   &       & 17'333 & 1'579 & 2'605 & 21'517 & 3'504 & 32'062 & 57'083 \\
    1929/30 & 317   &       & 17'105 & 1'579 & 3'288 & 21'972 & 4'461 & 32'747 & 59'180 \\
    1930/31 & 328   &       & 19'467 & 2'579 & 3'741 & 25'787 & 1'379 & 37'560 & 64'726 \\
    1931/32 & 334   &       & 20'103 & 1'853 & 3'372 & 25'328 & 3'972 & 33'449 & 62'749 \\
    1932/33 & 353   &       & 19'678 & 2'496 & 3'622 & 25'796 & 3'862 & 35'417 & 65'075 \\
    1933/34 & 365   &       & 20'725 & 3'336 & 4'844 & 28'905 & 4'330 & 37'647 & 70'882 \\
    1934/35 & 394   &       & 21'160 & 3'621 & 5'282 & 30'063 & 4'591 & 38'391 & 73'045 \\
    1935/36 & 423   &       & 22'429 & 3'770 & 5'125 & 31'324 & 4'957 & 39'221 & 75'502 \\
    1936/37 & 433   &       & 21'446 & 3'779 & 4'679 & 29'904 & 5'120 & 39'425 & 74'449 \\
    1937/38 & 437   &       & 20'249 & 3'434 & 5'350 & 29'033 & 4'813 & 39'324 & 73'170 \\
    1938/39 & 449   &       & 20'797 & 3'798 & 6'193 & 30'788 & 4'993 & 40'475 & 76'256 \\
    1939/40 & 470   &       & 17'792 & 2'958 & 5'807 & 26'557 & 2'908 & 31'247 & 60'712 \\
    1940/41 & 443   &       & 18'770 & 3'151 & 5'123 & 27'044 & 2'201 & 33'215 & 62'460 \\
    1941/42 & 490   &       & 19'161 & 3'294 & 5'225 & 27'680 & 2'488 & 34'288 & 64'456 \\
    1942/43 & 502   &       & 21'105 & 3'494 & 5'519 & 30'118 & 2'268 & 36'386 & 68'772 \\
    1943/44 & 552   &       & 18'198 & 3'970 & 7'280 & 29'448 & 2'349 & 39'560 & 71'357 \\
    1944/45 & 547   &       & 20'115 & 3'373 & 7'285 & 30'773 & 2'435 & 40'924 & 74'132 \\
    1945/46 & 581   &       & 23'503 & 4'621 & 9'232 & 37'356 & 2'781 & 48'144 & 88'281 \\
    1946/47 & 657   &       & 26'494 & 3'807 & 9'814 & 40'115 & 3'010 & 52'727 & 95'852 \\
    1947/48 & 691   &       & 20'644 & 4'142 & 10'528 & 35'314 & 2'869 & 57'338 & 95'521 \\
    1948/49 & 725   &       & 27'751 & 4'930 & 11'135 & 43'816 & 10'411 & 55'764 & 109'991 \\
    1949/50 & 756   &       & 29'713 & 5'503 & 11'511 & 46'727 & 11'582 & 58'732 & 117'041 \\
    \end{tabulary}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

I just don't see why these are suddenly not displayed anymore, because before I added the rest they were displayed. I use the following packages for tables:

```
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{tabularx}
```

Many thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Any errors? Maybe a 'too many floats'?

Comment: Standard setup of LaTeX allows only 18 floats ... so compare the number of shown tables and ... you know ;-)

Comment: If Christian's and my guess is correct, the easiest fix is to put `\clearpage` commands in places you know you'd have a natural page break.

Comment: Please consider the usage of `longtable` or some similar page for long tables....

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually, I have a further question that I nearly don't dare to ask: Is it actually possible to ask someone from here to perfectly modify the tables? When I started using Latex I never thought of including so many tables but suddenly, coming to the end of my master thesis and very little time left, I should optimize my appendix. Or would that be too much to ask in this community (I would absolutely understand it)?

Comment: @MadJens: We can help in solving problems, but it's too much work to optimize a bunch of tables ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A remedy could be the `morefloats` package and its options `maxfloats` and `morefloats`. This example works with dummy figures and dummy tables.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}


\usepackage[maxfloats=30,morefloats=12]{morefloats}

\usepackage{forloop}
\newcounter{loopcounter}
\begin{document}

\forloop{loopcounter}{1}{\value{loopcounter} < 16}{%
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{blaba}
\caption{Dummy figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\caption{Dummy table}

\end{table}
}



\end{document}
```